# Id пользователя в Django-rest-framework. Как автоматически присвоить id пользователя под которым я создаю новую запись

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import timedelta
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    IMPORTANCE = (
        ('H', 'High'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('L', 'Low'),
    )
    importance = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=IMPORTANCE)
    deadline = models.DateField()
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)          
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Task

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
        user = serializers.Field(source='user.username')

class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title','deadline','completed','importance','id','user',)
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status, permissions, generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import TaskSerializer, ListSerializer
from .models import Task
from .permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly

class taskCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    @api_view(['POST'])
    def taskCreate(request, obj):
        serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            obj.user = self.request.user
            serializer.save(obj.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: вы дважды используете `TaskSerializer` - так нужно или опечатка? Делаю такой вывод так как вы предоставили 2 сериализатора но используете один)

Comment: Использую 2 просто не заметил что 2й добавил)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было добавить поле user в TaskSerializer и добавил метод default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault() и в итоге получилась следующая запись:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
```